# Sigaction usage and interpretation

Tags: c, pointers, casting, struct

I am using sigaction for a signal and I am using a simple struct for that. I actually took it from the man page. Can someone explain to me what does the second line in the struct do? Also there is an error there:

```
error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'siginfo_t'



#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <getopt.h>

#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
#define MAX_WORD 256

void parseFile (FILE * fp, FILE *sketcher);
void handle_timeout(int signal);


struct sigaction {
 void     (*sa_handler)(int);
    void     (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
    sigset_t   sa_mask;
    int      sa_flags;
    void     (*sa_restorer)(void);
};
```

Comment: On some architectures a union is involved: do not assign to both sa_handler and sa_sigaction.
Seems they are the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not supposed to declare the `struct sigaction` yourself.  It is provided in the man page for your information, but it is actually declared by `<signal.h>`.

The second line in the struct defines a function pointer (as does the first, but with a different type).

Comment: Thank you. I should have read the man page more carefully. :)